# Vim in vs code, delete till end of line exclusive not working (`dv$`)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63670046/3557761) which suggests to use `dv$` to delete until the end of the line except the last character (this is quite useful for python if statements). It works in vim but it doesn't work in vs code with vim extension can this be fixed?

Comment: No idea about vs code, but in the case of python if statements, maybe `dt:` would be a useful work around? (i.e. `d`elete un`t`ill `:`)

Comment: FWIW, that thing is a Vim emulator, not Vim, so there is no reason whatsoever to expect anything that works in Vim to work the same in that emulator.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/1095) for this.

As suggested by @mattb in the comment, `dt:` is a good enough workaround for deleting the rest of a python if statement line.